# Speech bubble tooltip for images instead of links?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have some hidden speech bubbles that appear when you hover over links like this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmorrell2014/e4q7K/

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><a href="#" class="hoverbubble">Hover over me!<span>Hidden message here.</span></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
background-color: #FF0;
margin: 100px;
float: left;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}

a.hoverbubble {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.hoverbubble span {display: none;
}

a.hoverbubble:hover span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding: .5em;
content: attr(title);
min-width: px;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
height: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
top: -40px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 0.86em;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a.hoverbubble:hover span:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
content: "";
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: -20px;
left: 1em;
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to make this tooltip appear when you hover over an image instead of a link?

Comment: http://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/tooltip/SpryTooltipSample.html

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just use `:hover` on `img`. The details depend on how you want to position the tooltip relative to the image. If problems remain, show what you have actually tried and how the behavior differs from the expected or desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very simple solution, change your code like below.

```
<div id="container"><a href="#" class="hoverbubble"><img src="sample.gif" border="0" /><span>Hidden message here.</span></a></div>
```

If you don't want to use anchor tag itself then check the below jsfiddle, I have updated  your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/e4q7K/19/

Comment: It works!!Though is there a way to make the image an existing img id (etc "kuroko") to style it instead of an img src ? @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: or is there a way to style the image with this? width:100%; border:1px solid {color:border}; margin-bottom:6px;
{block:ifroundedsidepic}
-webkit-border-radius:100px; -moz-border-radius:100px; border-radius:100px;{/block:ifroundedsidepic}

Comment: Why not?    .hoverbubble img{width:100%; border:1px solid #000; margin-bottom:6px; -webkit-border-radius:100px; -moz-border-radius:100px; border-radius:100px;}